# ¿Cuándo se usa "libertar", y cuando "liberar"? ¿Qué diferencias hay entre las dos palabras?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, verbos, definiciones, diferencias-regionales

¿Cuándo es mas apropiado usar "liberar" o "libertar"? ¿Qué diferencias hay entre las dos? Connotan algo distinto?

Por ejemplo:

> Él los **libertó** de la esclavitud

o

> Él los **liberó** de la esclavitud

Comment: Hay un hilo muy interesante al respecto en Wordreference: http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=1862412 Suena mejor "liberar", pues "libertar" suena algo anacrónico.

Comment: Y ya que estamos, "librar" también se puede usar en muchos casos.

Comment: `libertar` solo usa cuando se habla de libertad, en cambio `liberar` es mucho más amplio y se puede usar en mucho más contextos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ambas se pueden usar porque son sinónimos.

[Diccionario de sinónimos y antónimos © 2005 Espasa-Calpe](http://www.wordreference.com/sinonimos/libertar)

Aunque liberar tiene un sentido más amplio que libertar.

Libertar (de Liberto) [en Ingles](http://www.latin-dictionary.net/definition/25606/liberto-libertare-libertavi-libertatus):

```
1. E:exempt 
2. liberate

Liberate: to give liberty to; make free.
```

Liberar (de Liberare) [en Ingles](http://www.latin-dictionary.net/definition/25600/libero-liberare-liberavi-liberatus):

```
1. acquit, absolve 
2. free 
3. liberate, release 
4. manumit

Manumit:  to free from slavery, servitude, etc; emancipate.
```

En el ejemplo que propones ambas son correctas.

Ejemplos en la Biblia.

Cuidado con el enlace es un PDF de 2100 páginas.
[Santa Biblia](http://media.ldscdn.org/pdf/lds-scriptures/holy-bible/holy-bible-spa.pdf):

- *Isaías capitulo 42: Isaías habla del Mesías — Jehová traerá Su ley y Su justicia, será una luz a las naciones y **liberará a los presos** — Alabad a Jehová.*
- *Isaías capitulo 45: Ciro **liberará de Babilonia a los cautivos de Israel** — Venid a Jehová (Cristo) y sed salvos — Ante Él se doblará toda rodilla y jurará toda lengua.*
- *Porque el que en el Señor **es llamado siendo esclavo, a liberto es del Señor**; asimismo, el que es llamado siendo libre, esclavo es de Cristo.*

Libertar es apropiado cuando al que liberas esta sujeto por una obligación moral.

Comment: Ojo, porque estás usando un tercer verbo, "*librar*", que no entra en la pregunta.

Comment: Cierto! mi mente se liberó. Lo eliminé.

Answer (score 2):

> libertar. (De liberto).
>
> 1. tr. **Poner en libertad** o soltar a quien está atado, preso o sujeto físicamente.
> 2. tr. Librar a alguien de una atadura moral.

.

> liberar. (Del lat. liberāre).
>
> 1. tr. Eximir a alguien de una obligación. U. t. c. prnl.
> 2. tr. Hacer que alguien o algo quede libre.
> 3. tr. Desprender, producir, secretar.

De las citas de la RAE queda claro que, con respecto a la esclavitud, el verbo correcto es **libertar**.

Comment: Será el correcto pero no lo usa ni dios. De hecho no lo usan ni cuando sacan a alguien de la carcel. Por cierto, respecto a la RAE cada vez limpia menos, fija menos y por supuesto da menos esplendor. De hecho ahora ya contempla la palabra "almondiga" anque redireccionando a la correcta "albondiga"... donde vamos a ir a parar. Pasado mañana incluirá "almuada" y la redireccionarán a "almohada". La conclusión que es que en mi vida he oído la palabra libertar referida a la acción, solo la he oído referida a personas (libertaria, libertador).

Comment: @YoMismo es cierto, la palabra "libertar" no se usa, pero si se usa "libertador" para referirse a los que lucharon en las guerras de independencia de los países latinoamericanos.

Answer (score 1):

Libertar es el acto de transformar a alguien en **liberto**, por lo que un libertador es alguien que liberta gente.

Liberar es el acto de dejar libre a alguien, y un liberador es alguien que libera gente.

Un liberto es alguien que antes estaba preso y ha sido liberado, por lo que para libertar a alguien hay que liberarlo, y viceversa. Ambas palabras son por tanto en esencia sinónimos.

Answer (score 1):

Ambos verbos, *liberar* y *libertar* son sinónimos perfectos. Esto es, no hay diferencia alguna en el significado del uno o del otro.

*Libertar* ha caído en desuso en muchos países hispanoparlantes. Sin embargo, si alguien usa el verbo *libertar*, o sus conjugaciones, será perfectamente entendido.

Answer (score 0):

The word "libertar" is not used. I can only think of the honorific title "libertador" (the one who gives freedom). In Peru it is only used for Simón Bolívar and José de San Martín (the Venezuelan and Argentine generals who fought the Wars of Independence). It is not even used for the Peruvian president who abolished slavery, Ramón Castilla.

Answer (score -3):

Liberarador.. es quien libera de una trampa mortal o ataduras o prisión pero puede seguir siendo esclavo de una persona, una idea,un sistema
Libertador... da la libertad absoluta en todo aspecto y sentido.
(ES MI HUMILDE OPINIÓN)

Comment: Creo que deberías clarificar un poco mejor lo que quieres expresar. Yo no creo que esta respuesta responda a la pregunta original (libertar vs liberar), ya q haces demasiado hincapié en Liberador/libertador. Deberías explicar un poco más por qué piensas que cada término tiene esas connotaciones, a ser posible con alguna referencia para apoyarlo.